# XMLSerializer create a new file after n lines (rows)

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have a problem with XMLSerializer:
I have a list  and want to write the content of the list into an XML with XMLSerializer. The whole thing works fine too.
But after n lines I want to write the data into a new XML with XMLSerializer, but the data is always written into the existing XML.

How can I solve it that after n lines a new XML file is created?

The code to serialize:

```
 private void SaveLogFile()
    {
        bf = new BaseFunctions();
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<LVProperties>));
            TextWriter wr = new StreamWriter(FilePath);

            seri.Serialize(wr, FileWatcher.Data);
            wr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            bf.app_Errorhandler(ex);
            return;
        }
    }
```

the code to collect data for Listview and datatable to serialize:

```
 public static List<LVProperties> Data = new List<LVProperties>();
    [STAThread]
    private void LogDataToLV()
    {
        ff = new FileFunctions();
        vlp = new LVProperties();
        bf = new BaseFunctions();

        bf.ReadAppInfos();

        _lvLogMe.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate ()
        {

            if (bf.osVersion.Major == 6 && bf.osVersion.Minor >= 2 || bf.osVersion.Major >= 10 && bf.osVersion.Minor >= 0)
            {
                LogMeUser = ff.getFileDetails(LogMePath, LogMeFile, FileFunctions.FileDetailInfo.Title); //Problem mit InvalidCastException!!
                LogMeSize = ff.getFileDetails(LogMePath, LogMeFile, FileFunctions.FileDetailInfo.Size);
            }
            else
            {
                LogMeUser = "not supported by OS";
                LogMeSize = "unknown";
            }
            _lvLogMe.Items.Add(new LVProperties { lv_LogMeDate = LogMeDate, lv_LogMeEvent = LogMeEvent, lv_LogMeFile = LogMeFile, lv_LogMePath = LogMePath, lv_LogMeUser = LogMeUser, lv_LogMeSize = LogMeSize });
            Data.Add(new LVProperties { lv_LogMeDate = LogMeDate, lv_LogMeEvent = LogMeEvent, lv_LogMeFile = LogMeFile, lv_LogMePath = LogMePath, lv_LogMeUser = LogMeUser, lv_LogMeSize = LogMeSize });
            _lvLogMe.SelectedIndex = _lvLogMe.Items.Count - 1;
            _tbLogCount.Text = _lvLogMe.Items.Count.ToString();
            if (VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(_lvLogMe) > 0)
            {
                Border border = (Border)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(_lvLogMe, 0);
                ScrollViewer scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0);
                scrollViewer.ScrollToBottom();
            }
            _lvLogMe.UpdateLayout();
            _lvLogMe.DataContext = Data;
            LVRowCount = _lvLogMe.Items.Count;

            if (sXML.SaveLogAuto == "true")
            {
                if (LVRowCount == 10)
                {
                    SaveLogFile();
                }
            }

            if (_lvLogMe.Items.Count == 10)
            {
                _lvLogMe.Items.Clear();
                Data.Clear();
            }


        }));
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your code as well?

Answer (score 0):

XML Serializer cannot have an array/list at the root.  Since you have a list you must wrap the list in another class.  To be able to move to a position in the xml you have to use an xml reader.  See code below :

```
   public class Test
    {
        BaseFunctions bf = new BaseFunctions();
        private void SaveLogFile()
        {
            bf = new BaseFunctions();
            Root root = new Root();
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
            try
            {
                XmlSerializer seri = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Root);
                XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
                settings.Indent = true;
                XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, settings);

                seri.Serialize(writer, root);
                stream.Position = 0;

                XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(stream);

                reader.ReadToFollowing("Node");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
    public class BaseFunctions
    {
    }
    public class Root
    {
        [XmlElement("Properties")]
        List<LVProperties> properties = new List<LVProperties>();
    }
    public class LVProperties
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If i have a little bit time, i will try it...